# mousewheel event listener above iframe

Tags: jquery

Is it even possible to know when a mousewheel is triggered when mouse is above an iframe on non webkit browsers such as firefox, oprera, ie and so on?

I am using the jquery mousewheel plugin. Everything works fine in chrome and safari, even if my mouse is hovering above an iframe, for example facebook comments or the facebook like box, which uses iframes. But on FF and IE and Opera the mousewheel event doesnt fire when mouse is hovering above an iframe. Very frustrating.

Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

http://9gag.com/fast#1217289

As you can see, no matter what browser you are using, you can still scroll when above the facebook comments.

(or maybe they are actually doing a negative margin to hide the original scrollbar? :p)

Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Does the event ever fire? FF uses a different way of doing the mouse wheel

```
    function wheel(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            Zoom(!(e.wheelDelta != 'undefined' && e.wheelDelta <= 0) || (e.detail != 'undefined' && e.detail > 0));
    }
```

Detail is for FF and IE and wheelDelta is for Chrome

Comment: it fires as it should, except when the mouse is above an iframe